# Printing a Rendered XAML Form

Tags: xaml, printing

I can't seem to find a solution for this issue.  I have a simple form which I created as a test for an insurance log file.  When I open the xaml file in the web browser (IE 8) it displays the form properly, but when I go to print it to a printer, the dialog box appears as normal, but nothing happens after hitting the print button.  Ultimately I'd need this to print as part of a document imaging system, but I was using the web browser to single out that variable.

I am very new to xaml, so I may have overlooked something simple to enable the rendered form to be printed.  Is there something that needs to be added to the code somewhere?  Or do I need to add a driver to my printer to be able to compile XAML into a printable format?  Below is the code that I have currently.  I'm using WPF with Visual Studio Express 2013.  Thanks!

```
<Grid x:Name="Form"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Width="500" Height="620" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="xmlData" XPath="/data" IsAsynchronous="False">
            <x:XData>
                <data xmlns="">

                </data>
            </x:XData>
        </XmlDataProvider>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="79*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="POLICY HANDLING - INCEPTION" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Height="12" Margin="0,4"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="120" Height="40">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="15*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Width="40" TextAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0,0,0,3" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Width="40" TextAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0,0,0,3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="TEAM" Height="14" FontSize="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="TIA PRODUCER" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="14" FontSize="10" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,3" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    </Grid>



</Grid>
```

Comment: Ah yes, my answer was C#, this question was tagged WPF so i glossed over the browser bit.  I was able to toss your code into a xaml file and it printed just as it showed on the screen.

Comment: Thanks for your replies!  It must be a printer driver issue we're having here then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have it figured out now.  I gave the grid/form a background color ("White") and it prints just fine now.  It had been transparent before.  It must be a constraint of the document imaging system we're using.

Comment: ah..  when i printed it, I had given it a Background so i could be sure that I was getting the whole grid.  Sorry I didn't connect the dots and saved you a little more time.  Glad it's sorted.